# Using sed to extract specific columns

Tags: sed

I was just wondering how would I extracted a specific column using sed?(My system has sed installed, so no awk unfortunately :( ). I got a text file like the following:

```
Business Name,Description,Address,Postal Code,Email,Phone,Fax,Web Site,City,Latitude,Longitude,Keywords,Mailing Address,Indigenous Ownership,Region,Type,Industry Sector,Year Formed,Number of Employees,Primary Contact,Contact Title,Twitter,Facebook,When Updated
Duz Cho Construction LP,"Duz Cho Construction is an earthworks construction company doing site development, road access, and reclamation for the oil and gas, wind energy, mining and other civil works construction within the traditional territory of McLeod Lake Indian Band.",4821 South Access Road,V0C 1J0,albertson@dcclp.com,250-788-3120,250-788-3188,https://duzcho.com/duz-cho-construction/,Chetwynd,55.6963381,-121.6266684,Duz Cho Construction LP  23  Construction,"4821 South Access Road, Chetwynd, BC V0C 1J0",TRUE,Northeast,Community Owned Company,23  Construction,2002,55 to 99,Jacob Albertson,General Manager,,https://www.facebook.com/DuzChoConstruction/,2012-04-15
Gilwa Consulting Inc.,"Gilwa Consulting Inc. (GCI) is an Indigenous owned and operated business that provides advisory services for all participants in the construction industry engaged in developing, implementing, and/or executing on contractual agreements between Indigenous peoples, industry (EPC, EPCM, Contractors), and/or government.",710 Ruston Road,V1X3Y2,gilwaconsultingoffice@gmail.com,778-215-1888,,http://www.gilwaconsulting.com,Kelowna,49.8804877,-119.4070893,"Gilwa Consulting Inc. 54  Professional, scientific and technical services","710 Ruston Road, Kelowna, BC V1X 3Y2",TRUE,Thompson / Okanagan,Private Company,"54  Professional, scientific and technical services",2019,1 to 4,Thomas Nyce,Director,,,2021-04-14
HSI  Hobbs Strategic Insights,"Offering a full suite of strategic planning, business consultation, corporate communications and success & inclusion coaching services, HSI works with you to manifest transformational initiatives from conception to implementation. HSI is a leader in Indigenous reconciliation work, and diversity & inclusion initiatives for corporate entities.",,V3M 0J4,info@strategicinsights.ca,604-626-8296,,https://strategicinsights.ca,,,,"HSI  Hobbs Strategic Insights 54  Professional, scientific and technical services",,TRUE,Lower Mainland / Southwest,Private Company,"54  Professional, scientific and technical services",2021,1 to 4,Sasha Hobbs,Principal Strategist,,,2021-04-14
Bigfoot Donuts,"Bigfoot Donuts is a locally owned and operated bakery and caf in the heart of Downtown Courtenay. Specializing in handcrafted, made from scratch, quality, coffee and donuts, with a side of fun.",463 A 5th Street,V9N 1J7,yum@bigfootdonuts.com,250-871-6603,,https://www.bigfootdonuts.com/,Courtenay,49.6902502,-125.0032691,Bigfoot Donuts 72  Accommodation and food services,"463 A 5th Street, Courtenay BC V9N 1J7",TRUE,Vancouver Island and Coast,Private Company,72  Accommodation and food services,2017,5 to 9,Lyndsey Bell,Owner,,https://www.facebook.com/Bigfoot.Donuts/,2021-04-14
Refocus Communications & Fundraising,"Refocus helps non-profit organizations more deeply engage their community and supporters so that, together, they can do great things in the world.
We work with charities across Canada, helping them build fundraising programs with an engagement and communications focus.","20543 96 Ave., Unit 31",V1M 3W3,aimee@refocuscommunications.com,778.875.3439,,http://www.refocuscommunications.com,Langley ,49.1776159,-122.6564416,Refocus Communications & Fundraising 81  Other services (except public administration),"20543 96 Ave., Unit 31, Langley, BC V1M 3W3",TRUE,Lower Mainland / Southwest,Private Company,81  Other services (except public administration),2017,1 to 4,Aime Lindenberger,"CEO, Chief Engagement Officer",,,2021-03-31
Turtle Island Connections,"Turtle Island Connections curates Subscription boxes filled with Indigenous creations. Our box, the Turtle Shell, focuses on our spiritual, mental, emotional, and physical well-being. Each Shell contains Indigenous art, Cultural teachings, Nourishment, Self-care products and Donation to the Vancouver Aboriginal Health Society.",3139 Brandt Crescent,V9L 6W6,info@turtleislandconnections.ca,250.710.7685,,https://www.turtleislandconnections.ca,Duncan,48.7633914,-123.7137629,Turtle Island Connections 44-45  Retail trade,"3139 Brandt Crescent, Duncan BC V9L 6W6",TRUE,Vancouver Island and Coast,Partnership,44-45  Retail trade,2021,1 to 4,Lindsay Myers,Co-Founder,,https://www.facebook.com/TurtleIslandConnections,2021-03-31
Bulkley Valley Roofing Ltd,"Specializing in Commercial, Industrial and Residential Roofing. Fully certified and insured for hot roofing work. Red-seal Journeymen staffed.","Unit 3-3167 Tatlow rd, ",V0J 2N0,bvroof2@gmail.com,250-846-9446,250-846-9440,,Smithers,54.7698334,-127.143943,Bulkley Valley Roofing Ltd 23  Construction,"Unit 3-3167 Tatlow rd, Smithers BC V0J 2N0",TRUE,North Coast,Development Corporation,23  Construction,2000,5 to 9,Murray Olivier,Owner/operator,,,2021-03-31
North Coast Helicopters,Northcoast Helicopters provides experienced long-line pilots who are seasoned in diamond drill support and mountain flying. Northcoast Helicopters provides wildfire fighting services to various private and government agencies.,2555 Seal Cove Road unit 123,V8J 3P6,craig@northcoasthelicopters.com,250-631-6031,,http://www.northcoasthelicopters.com,Prince Rupert,54.3369741,-130.3125632,"North Coast Helicopters 21  Mining, quarrying, and oil and gas extraction","2555 Seal Cove Road unit 123, Prince Rupert BC V8J 3P6",TRUE,North Coast,Private Company,"21  Mining, quarrying, and oil and gas extraction",2005,5 to 9,Kristen,Owner,,,2021-03-31
Park West Professional Services,Call Center,"Suite 811, 100 Park Royal, Suite 200",V7T 1A2,matt@mattvickers.com,604-210-1483,,,West Vancouver,49.3251879,-123.1358334,"Park West Professional Services 54  Professional, scientific and technical services","100 Park Royal, Suite 200, West Vancouver, BC V7T 1A2",TRUE,Lower Mainland / Southwest,Private Company,"54  Professional, scientific and technical services",2013,10 to 19,Matt Vickers,Owner,,,2021-03-31
Afterglow Hair Lounge,"Get your glow on. We strive to provide our guests the same quality one-on-one service small towns are renowned for, with the style, talent and professionalism of the city. We're proud to have been nominated and featured as some of the ""Best of Powell River"" stylists in 2017, 2018, 2019 and 2020 and have a shared dedication to maintain improve client experiences in years to come.  Look no further for the best wedding stylists of the upper Sunshine Coast  available year-round for events in-salon*, seven days a week. Come experience AfterGlow.",7075 Alberni Street,V8A2C2,info@afterglowhairlounge.com,604.485.2075,, http://www.afterglowhairlounge.com,Powell River,49.8468725,-124.5196439,Afterglow Hair Lounge 81  Other services (except public administration),,TRUE,Vancouver Island and Coast,Private Company,81  Other services (except public administration),2011,5 to 9,Holly Barnes,Owner/operator,https://twitter.com/afterglowhair,https://www.facebook.com/AfterGlowHairLounge,2021-03-10
Dawson Analytics Inc.,"Dawson Analytics is a consulting company specializing in research development and design, data analysis and interpretation, and program/policy evaluation. Our company sources and analyzes data to provide our clients with powerful insights into their processes, outcomes and future endeavours.",22839 Gilbert Drive,V4R 0G4,DawsonAnalytics@outlook.com,604.961.5129,,http://www.dawsonanalytics.com,Maple Ridge,49.2512469,-122.5874728,Dawson Analytics Inc.  51  Information and cultural industries,"22839 Gilbert Drive, Maple Ridge, BC V4R 0G4",TRUE,Lower Mainland / Southwest,Private Company,51  Information and cultural industries,2021,1 to 4,Stephanie Johnston,Vice President,,,2021-03-10
Bridging Innovations Inc.,Management consulting and Aboriginal relations services,,V2B 4G5,bob@bridginginnovations.com,250.571.9566,,https://bridginginnovations.com,Kamloops BC,50.6745,-120.3273, Bridging Innovations Inc. 55  Management of companies and enterprises,Postal Code: V4R 0G4,TRUE,Thompson / Okanagan,Private Company,55  Management of companies and enterprises,1997,1 to 4,Bob Miller,Onwer & President,,,2021-03-10
Fraser Valley Office Systems,"Fraser Valley Office Systems is a First Nation owned authorized Ricoh dealership. Ricohs leading edge approach to technology and document workflow have helped many corporations streamline document production and increase efficiency while reducing costs.As the Fraser Valley's Local Authorized Ricoh Dealer, we have partnered with Ricoh to bring you the latest office system solutions for your copying, printing, scanning, faxing, and document management needs. We pride ourselves on offering exemplary all-inclusive service to our customers. We take the time to analyze and understand your print, copy, and document management needs so that we can provide you with a solution that saves you time, money, and hassle. We have locations across BC and Yukon to offer service across western Canada. Our ownership group is the Tle Nax Tawei Group (TTG) is the business arm of the Teslin Tlingit First Nation and is owned by the Teslin Tlingit Council Business Trust. TleNax Tawei Limited Partnership (TTLP) and TleNax Tawei Industrial Limited Partnership (TTLPI) are business holding partnerships, managed by one partner Tle Nax Tawei Inc. TTG strives to provide the Trust with good financial returns and promotes self-sufficiency for the Teslin Tlingit First Nation.",Unit 4-2582 Mount Lehman Rd. ,V4X2N3,jnickel@freaservalleyofficesystems.com,604.621.3866,,http://fraservalleyofficesystems.com/,Abbotsford,49.0490255,-122.3828463,"Fraser Valley Office Systems 54  Professional, scientific and technical services",Unit 4-2582 Mount Lehman Rd. Abbotsford BC V4X2N3,TRUE,Lower Mainland / Southwest,Community Owned Company,"54  Professional, scientific and technical services",2016,10 to 19,Jonathan Nickel,Business Development Manager,,,2021-03-05
Shxw'owhamel Ventures,"Shxw?whml Ventures is a proud Indigenous owned and operated construction company based within Shxw?whml First Nation traditional territory in Hope, BC. We have a diverse set of service offerings with vast experience to take on any project, big or small. With a highly skilled Indigenous and local workforce, we have the capacity to deliver high quality work and products. List of services include: Heavy Civil, structural building, underground utilities, environmental construction, safety and security, camp construction, equipment hauling and more.",58700-A St. Elmo Rd.,V0X1L2, alfred.james@shxwowhamel.ca,604-860-9760,,https://shxwowhamelventures.ca/,Hope,49.3512554,-121.5934023,Shxw'owhamel Ventures 23 - Construction,"58700-A St Elmo Rd, Hope, BC V0X 1L2",TRUE,Lower Mainland / Southwest,: Community Owned Company,23  Construction,2015,20 to 49,Alfred James,CEO,https://twitter.com/ShxwowhamelVLP,https://www.facebook.com/ShxwowhamelVentures,2021-03-05
Surely Building Company Inc.,Our ownership group is the Tle Nax Tawei Group (TTG) is the business arm of the Teslin Tlingit First Nation and is owned by the Teslin Tlingit Council Business Trust.,3592 Turner Street,V5K 2H9,churchill.landan@gmail.com,250.793.7300,,,Vancouver,49.27882,-123.0283148,Surely Building Company Inc. 23  Construction,"3592 Turner Street, Vancouver, BC",TRUE,Lower Mainland / Southwest,Private Company,23  Construction,2021,1 to 4,Landan Churchill,Owner,,,2021-02-22
West Coast Pile Driving 2013 Ltd,"We supply and install driven foundation piles, sheet pile shoring, and various other ground improvement technologies.",12955 Katonien Street,V2W0J2,ryan@westcoastpiledriving.com,604.803.6569,,http://www.westcoastpiledriving.com,Maple Ridge,49.2377,-122.49499,West Coast Pile Driving 2013 Ltd 23  Construction,"12955 Katonien Street, Maple Ridge V2W0J2",TRUE,Lower Mainland / Southwest,Private Company,23  Construction,2013,1 to 4,Ryan Johnston, President,,,2021-02-22
Indigenous Canada Solutions Ltd. (ICS),Ricohs leading edge approach to technology and document workflow have helped many corporations streamline document production and increase efficiency while reducing costs.,401-4th Avenue West,V8J 1P7,angus@ics2020.ca,,,,Prince Rupert,54.31194,-130.3232,"Indigenous Canada Solutions Ltd. (ICS) 54  Professional, scientific and technical services","401-4th Avenue West, Prince Rupert, BC V8J1P7",TRUE,North Coast,Private Company,"54  Professional, scientific and technical services",2020,1 to 4,Maynard Angus,President,,,2021-02-22
New Age Furnace and Duct Cleaning Ltd.,,2860 Auburn Road ,V4T3B2,candaceland79@hotmail.com,780.937.3907,,https://newageductcleaning.business.site/,West Kelowna,49.855711,-119.603322,New Age Furnace and Duct Cleaning Ltd. 81  Other services (except public administration),2860 Auburn Road West Kelowna V4T3B2,TRUE,Thompson / Okanagan,,81  Other services (except public administration),2018,1 to 4,Candace Landry,Owner,,,2021-02-22
BGW FILM STUDIOS,I am focusing on the self-reliance and independence of the indigenous people by creating documentary films that highlight students and professionals.,"7-1451 Perkins Road, ", V9W4R8,admin@bgwfilmstudios.com,250.850.9344,,http://www.bgwfilmstudios.com,Campbell River,50.0472431,-125.2730345,BWG FILM 81  Other services (except public administration),": 7-1451 Perkins Road, Campbell River, BC V9W4R8",TRUE,Vancouver Island and Coast,Private Company,81  Other services (except public administration),2013,1 to 4,Billy George Williams,Owner / WEO, https://twitter.com/bgwfilmstudios,https://www.facebook.com/BGWFILMSTUDIOS,2021-02-22
The Owls Path,"As the Fraser Valley's Local Authorized Ricoh Dealer, we have partnered with Ricoh to bring you the latest office system solutions for your copying, printing, scanning, faxing, and document management needs.",2975 3rd Ave ,V9Y 9B4,joel@theowlspath.com,250-206-1674,, http://www.theowlspathmarket.com,Port Alberni,49.2331419,-124.8093691,"The Owls Path 71  Arts, entertainment and recreation","2975 3rd Ave, Port Alberni, BC V9
```

Theres a lot of lines theres more lines in the file but thats enough of an example I guess. Now I need to extract the information that is in the Business Name column. So I tried:

```
sed -n '^[^,]*,{1}p' $1
```

Where $1 is the filename read from user input.
I also tried:

```
sed -n '\^\[\^,\]*,{1}p' $1
```

I'm more familiar with grep REs thats why they look like grep REs instead of sed ones. Just starting using sed recently.

Comment: What system is this? Which version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such a simple task as this, even `awk` seems like overkill - you can use `cut`:

```
cut -d, -f 1 "$1"
```

If you *must* use `sed`, then probably the simplest way is to match the first comma and everything thereafter, and replace it with nothing:

```
sed 's/,.*//' "$1"
```

or

```
sed -n 's/,.*//p' "$1"
```

if you want to exclude from the output any lines that do not contain a match (i.e. lines that do not contain at least one comma).

If you are determined to do it by matching the first column contents explicitly, then either

```
sed 's/\([^,]*\),.*/\1/' "$1"
```

or (with Extended Regular Expressions)

```
sed -E 's/([^,]*),.*/\1/' "$1"
```

with `-n` and `p` optional as before.

If you intended `{1}` to be a quantifier, then note that in a Basic Regular Expression the braces need to be escaped as well `\{1\}` - however you don't need an explicit quantifier to match one occurrence of something. You can add a `^` anchor to the start of the pattern if you wish, but I don't think it's required here.

Comment: The reason I was asking was because I need to do multiple columns so yep I would prefer not creating multiple helper files and etc..

Comment: I tried adding in a command line agruement by going sed -E 's/([^,]*),'"$2"'/\1/' "$1" > file1.txt; but it does not work??